# width and init problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an animation chain I have two problems:

1. The init function it doesn't set the width straight way for the first `div.container`
2. On my mouseenter function where i have to use -10 for the `#menu` so the width doesn't expand out side the last `div.containers`

Here it is on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gygk7/3/)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


        function init() {
            $('#menu').css({ 'width': $('.container:first').width(), 'height': $('.container:first').height() });
        }
        init();
        $('.menu-item').mouseover(function () {
            var curr = $(this).closest('.container');
            var next = curr.next('.container');
            var index = curr.index() + 1
            $('#menu').animate({ 'width': curr.position().left + curr.width() + next.width() - 9 /* don't know why i have to use -9*/ })
            .find('.container').css({ 'opacity': 0.5 })
            .filter('.container:nth-child(' + index + ')').nextAll().animate({ 'left': curr.position().left + curr.width() });
        });
    });
```

CSS:

```
.spacer
    {
        background-color:Red; width:5px; height:200px; position:absolute; z-index:1000;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<table border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="menu" style="background-color:Black; width:2000px; height:300px;top:5px; left:50px  ">
                <div class="container" id="1" style="left:0; width:200px; height:220px; z-index:999; position:absolute; background-color:Aqua">
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 1</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 2</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 3</div>
                </div>
                <div class="container" id="2" style="left:0; width:200px; height:300px; z-index:998; position:absolute; background-color:Blue">
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 4</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 5</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 6</div>
                </div>
                <div class="container" id="3" style="left:0; width:200px; height:400px; z-index:997; position:absolute; background-color:Fuchsia">
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 7</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 8</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 9</div>
                </div>
                <div class="container" id="4" style="left:0; width:200px; height:500px; z-index:996; position:absolute; background-color:Green; float:left">
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 10</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 11</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 12</div>
                </div>
                <div class="container" id="5" style="left:0; width:200px; height:600px; z-index:995; position:absolute; background-color:Lime; float:left">
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 10</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 11</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 12</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your first question, the answer to your 2nd question is that the -10 should be

```
$('#menu').position().left
```

You need to take into account that the menu itself is not right against the edge of the screen.

Comment: thankyou @kingjiv do you know how i could add a div in between each animation, beteen the containers that slide out thats what i want to be able to do. also my init fucntion isn't setting the #menu div to the width of the first div.container thats what i was trying to say

Comment: It actually is updating the width on init, it's just that with .5 opacity and 5 stacked divs you can't really see the effect of the black through all of those divs.  See this slightly updated fiddle.  I removed the backgrounds on the divs and put borders so you coudl see the animation of the black  http://jsfiddle.net/gygk7/6/

Comment: also not sure what you mean by adding divs between animation.  Where do the divs go?

Comment: adding the divs in between the sliding panels. i want to add a red div 200px height and 5px wide. this might involve removing and adding. I hope this is clear enough but can you help me accomplish this

Comment: also when i want to check if something is exists like if($('#spacer')){alert('Hellowrld")} it always returns true hoiw do check if something exists

Comment: it returns true because it will always return an object, the object may be empty.  I usually use .length `if($('#spacer').length>0)`